# Twilio Flask app video call is not connecting over a public IP address

Tags: python, flask, twilio, twilio-video

I created an application in Flask Python with a frontend in HTML and Twilio SDK JavaScript version 2.3.0.

A video call is working on local host, but if I try the same app over [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) with a valid certificate, it is fetching the token correctly for the video call, but it can't establish a connection to Twilio.

I have tried forcing the browser permissions for the camera and audio to allow and it did not make a difference.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: What do you mean by *"for the sit for camera and audio to allow"*? It seems incomprehensible. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71871662/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to load the Twilio script, you need to enable https in both the website and the script. Otherwise, it will mix up HTTP and HTTPS and fail. So there are two simple things to do:

- put your website over HTTPS
- load the `https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/video/releases/2.3.0/twilio-video.min.js` file over HTTPS in file *index.html*.

This will solve your problem.